# Add Validation for billing_phone in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, billing

I currently have wordpress/woocommerce and a **billing_phone** valiation function (provided below) which works within the Checkout.

I require the same checks as the front end in the register.

My register form is custom and i add **billing_phone** in form of registeration.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'user_validate_billing_phone');

function user_validate_billing_phone() {

    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) && !empty( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) { 

        if ( !preg_match('/^05[0-9]{8}$/D', str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) ) {

        //  Error: Billing Phone Number is Invalid.
            wc_add_notice(__('رقم الجوال غير صحيح', 'woocommerce'));

        }

        $existing_billing_phone = get_users( 'meta_value=' . str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) );

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        if ( !empty( $existing_billing_phone ) ) {

            if ( $current_user->billing_phone != str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {

            // Error: Billing Phone Number Already Exists.
                wc_add_notice(__('رقم الجوال مستخدم لحساب اخر', 'woocommerce'));

            }
            else { 
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For the record. You have added a billing phone field to the registration form? and for that field you want to provide validation? if so, can you add the code to your question you used to create that field?

Comment: yes, i add code in my question